# excelファイルから複数シートを読み込み、別々のDataFrameを作成する方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下の通り、excelファイルから複数シート（ファイル内の全シート）を読み込んだ後、
各シートごとに任意の名前をつけDataFrame化したいと考えています。

```
all_sheets = pd.read_excel('分析データ.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

具体的には、本ファイルには合計４シートあり、それぞれ data_4、data_5、data_6、data_7 という名前をつけ4つのデータフレームを作りたいと考えています。

各シートの値は以下の記述で取り出せたのですが、その後DataFrame化には`pd.DataFrame(all_sheets[v])` 等を使うのかと思うのですが、上手くいかず。

```
for k, v in enumerate(all_sheets):
    print(all_sheets[v])
```

命名のため連番のfor文を回しながらDataFrameを作成する方法について、アドバイスいただければ幸いです。

Comment: `all_sheets` は OrderdDict 型のインスタンスですので、`for k, v in all_sheets.items():` とすれば `k` にシート名、`v` に対応するデータフレームが入ります。

Comment: データフレームを `data_4、data_5、data_6、data_7` という別々の変数に格納するのではなく、リストにするという方法もあります。`dfs = list(all_sheets.values())` この場合、`dfs[0]` が最初のシート、`dfs[1]` が2番めのシートに対応するデータフレームになります。

Comment: その場合は `data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7 = list(all_sheets.values())` とすると良いかと。

Comment: その形でデータフレーム化できることを知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。ちなみに、、for文等でdata4～7の連番での命名は可能でしょうか？？（今回は4ファイルなのでアナログに記述できますが、数が多くなった場合にどのようにしたらよいかと思いまして、、）

Comment: for i in range(4,8):
    df[i] =  list(all_sheets.values())　　のような記述も考えましたが上手くいきませんでした。。

Comment: たとえば、`i = 4; for v in all_sheets.values(): globals()['data_' + str(i)] = v; i+=1` とします(`;` を改行に変えて下さい)。

Comment: globals()も初めて知りました。。やりたかったことが実現できました。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます！